# How to connect 2 queries SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to connect these 2 queries to receive one that gives such a response:

```
user_name  room_name_reserved    room_name_biggest_time 

user_1       room_1                  room_2
```

1. room_name_reserved - most often reserved room by user
2. room_name_biggest_time  - room when user spent the most time

1 query:

```
 SELECT   
        us.name as user_name 
        ,ro.name as room_name_reserved
    FROM reservation re
    INNER JOIN user us on us.id = re.userid 
    INNER JOIN room ro on ro.id = re.roomid
    GROUP BY us.name, ro.name
    HAVING COUNT(room_name_reser) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservation re1 
        WHERE re1.userid = re.userid 
        GROUP BY re1.roomid
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

2 query :

```
SELECT   
    us.name as user_name 
    ,ro.name as room_name_biggest_time 
from Reservation re
INNER JOIN user us on us.id = re.userid  
INNER JOIN room ro on ro.id = re.roomid
WHERE (strftime('%s', re.EndsAt) - strftime('%s', re.StartsAt)) = (SELECT MAX((strftime('%s', re1.EndsAt) - strftime('%s', re1.StartsAt))) as time FROM Reservation re1 where re1.UserId = re.userid
```

ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 1 )

Comment: Please provide a fiddle and desired result for it. *How to connect these 2 queries to receive one that gives such a response:* Drop existing queries and create needed one from the beginning.

Comment: Also you must specify what must be returned if someone reserves 2 or more rooms for the same and maximal time. And the same for time spent.

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Please provide a [db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the two query as subquery  in join

```
select t1.user_name, t1.room_name_reserved , t2.room_name_biggest_time
from (
  select   
      us.name as user_name, 
      ro.name as room_name_reserved
  from reservation re
  inner join user us on us.id = re.userid 
  inner join room ro on ro.id = re.roomid
  group by us.name, ro.name
  having count(room_name_reser) = (
      select count(*)
      from reservation re1 
      where re1.userid = re.userid 
      group by re1.roomid
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1) 
) t1 
left  join  (
select   
    us.name as user_name, 
    ro.name as room_name_biggest_time 
from Reservation re
inner join user us on us.id = re.userid  
inner join room ro on ro.id = re.roomid
Where (strftime('%s', re.EndsAt) - strftime('%s', re.StartsAt)) = (
    SELECT Max((strftime('%s', re1.EndsAt) - strftime('%s', re1.StartsAt))) as time 
    from Reservation re1
    where re1.UserId = re.userid 
    order by time desc limit 1
    )
) t2 on t1.user_name = t2.user_name
```

Comment: Nice, exacly i need this solution, i have one more question, i want add also time condition (from, to) and i add at the end  `Where t1.start >"2020-02-16 19:17:38" and t1.thend < "2020-02-16 19:17:38"`, that will be ok ?

Comment: You can add   condition from to  in the both the inner  subquery   .. of course  but not in the outer query because are not presente in the select clause for the subquery so are not visible to the outer select

Comment: Yes, i know that way i add to 'select' `re.StartsAt AS start,
      re.EndsAt AS thend`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySql, here's a little hack that can work:

```
SELECT 
    user_name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(room_name ORDER BY n_reservations DESC), ',', 1) as room_name_reserved,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(room_name ORDER BY total_stay DESC), ',', 1) as room_name_biggest_time
FROM (
    SELECT 
      us.name as user_name,
      ro.name as room_name,
      count(*) as n_reservations,
      sum(strftime('%s', re.EndsAt) - strftime('%s', re.StartsAt)) as total_stay
    FROM user u
    JOIN reservation re on us.id = re.userid
    JOIN room ro on ro.id = re.roomid
    GROUP BY us.name, ro.name
    ) t
GROUP BY user_name
```

**Explanation:**

With the subquery, aliased as `t`, we extract the total number of reservations (`count(*)`) and the total staying time (`sum(...)`) for each user/room, producing an intermediate output as follows:

```
user  room  n_reservations  total_stay
--------------------------------------
user1 room1 1               6000
user1 room2 2               3000
user1 room3 1               4000
user2 room2 1               9000
user2 room4 5               4000
```

With the outer query we `GROUP BY` user, and for each user we first group concat the room name using a sorting based on counts and sums made before (biggest value first), producing an intermediate output as follow:

```
user  group_concat#1     group_concat#2
---------------------------------------
user1 room2,room1,room3  room1,room3,room2
user2 room4,room2        room2,room4
```

Last step, we split by comma the output of the two `group_concat` mantaining only the first value, so final result will be:

```
user  room_name_reserved  room_name_biggest_time
-----------------------------------------------
user1 room2               room1
user2 room4               room2
```